# Why does this replace the initial values?

Tags: c

When I attempt to parse a text file and then print just the contents in  a singly linked list, every value is for some reason overwritten by the second last value. For instance, if the list is

a

b

c

d

the code will print those proper lines inside of the while loop, but then when I try to print the heads string at the end of the code the code will only print d for both the head and the heads next value.

```
    char buf[1024];
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);

    char *file_name = strtok(buf, "\n");
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name2,  "r");


    char *throwaway = fgets(buf, 1024, fp);

    struct bit_t *tail;
    struct bit_t *head;
    head = create_node(throwaway);
    printf("%s\n", head->pos1);
    int count;
    count = 0;
    //issue is that it is just overwriting the old results
    while( (fgets(buf, 1024, fp)) != NULL ) {

            printf("String : %s\n", buf);
            tail = insert_tail(head, create_node(buf));

            printf("%s\n", tail->pos1);
    }
    printf("Results : \n");
    printf("%s\n", head->pos1);
    printf("%s\n", head->next->pos1);

struct bit_t *create_node(char *pos1)

{
        struct bit_t *r;
        struct bit_t *current;

    r = malloc(sizeof(struct bit_t));
    if(!r) {
            exit(1);
    }
    r->next = NULL;
    r->pos1 = pos1;
    current = r;

    return current;

}

struct bit_t *insert_head(struct bit_t *head, struct bit_t *node)
{
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        return node;
}
struct  bit_t *insert_tail(struct bit_t *head, struct bit_t *node)
{
        struct bit_t *current;
        current = head;
        while(current->next !=  NULL) {
                current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = node;

        return node;;
}
```

The structure begin used is

```
struct bit_t {
    char *pos1;

    struct bit_t *next;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in your list points to `buf` but each iteration through your loop overwrites the contents of `buf`. To resolve the problem, each element needs to allocate storage space for the contents of `buf` and then copy the value of `buf`.